# Does my laptop have ROM?

Tags: bios

I have read that servers have ROM with BIOS. Do the laptops such as MAC and PC have the same mechanism ?  I do not see ROM configuration on the "About this mac" thus confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laptops have a ROM to the same extent as servers do (but in reality neither have ROM anymore - ROM = Read-Only Memory, ROM has been replaced with NVRAM - Nonvolatile RAM, which acts like ROM most of the time, except it allows you to upgrade it if you need to).